# When the "Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column" should really be an error

Tags: r, warnings

I have repeatedly encountered a situation where I had made a mistake in the names of the column names, but instead a creating an error message when I used that column, R set the value of the (non-existent) column equal to zero, and just produced a warning message.
I would like the use of a non-existent column name to result in an error message.7
I know it is possible to modify the R options to do exactly that, but I was wondering whether it is possible to do this for specific warning messages.

Comment: Could you please include a [mre] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: "R set the value of the (non-existent) column equal to zero" No, I don't believe that can happen. The value will be `NULL`. Anyway, please construct an example (example data + code) that demonstrate the problematic behavior and also show the desired output.

Comment: TestDF <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c(1,2,2), C = c(5,2,3))
CalSumBD <- function(df){
  returnval <- sum(df$B) +  sum(df$D)
  return(returnval)
}


TestVal <-  CalSumBD(TestDF)

Comment: In the example above, I don't even get a warning message. But  TestVal = 5 while I would really like an error message telling me that I just an non-existent column

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that extracting non-existing columns returns `NULL` and `help("sum")` says "For historical reasons, `NULL` is accepted and treated as if it were `integer(0)`."

You can use a `stopifnot` assertion to protect against `NULL` values:

```
TestDF <- data.frame(A = c("a", "b", "c"), B = c(1,2,2), C = c(5,2,3)) 

CalSumBD <- function(df){ 
  returnval <- sum(df$B) + sum(df$D)
  return(returnval) 
  } 
CalSumBD(TestDF) 
#[1] 5

mySum <- function(..., na.rm = FALSE) {
  stopifnot("NULL value in input" = all(!sapply(list(...), is.null)))
  sum(..., na.rm = na.rm)
}

CalSumBD_save <- function(df){ 
  returnval <- mySum(df$B) + mySum(df$D)
  return(returnval) 
} 

CalSumBD_save(TestDF) 
#Error in mySum(df$D) : NULL value in input
```